# Oracle NoSQL - what does mean : Table exists but definitions do not match

Tags: oracle-nosql

I run into this issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Error: User error in query: 
CREATE TABLE failed for table TEST: 
Table exists but definitions do not match
```

I added 2 new columns in my existing database using console, and added them in table creation statement. It hits the error when I run creating table again.
I checked everything, they all match, (name, type…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the order of columns matter when you create a table. Did you validate this ?  The IF NOT EXISTS in the CREATE TABLE clause checks for the same structure of the table. Please refer the documentation below for more details.https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/21.1/sqlreferencefornosql/create-table.html

This inform you that the table that you are trying to create exits but the structure is not the same. It could be useful.

A sample to show the error when order of columns is changed:

```
sql-> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing_tbl(id INTEGER, firstName STRING,
    lastName STRING,
PRIMARY KEY (id));

Statement completed successfully

sql-> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing_tbl(id INTEGER, firstName STRING,

    lastName STRING,

PRIMARY KEY (id));

Statement did not require execution

sql-> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing_tbl(id INTEGER, lastName STRING,
firstName STRING,
PRIMARY KEY (id));


Error handling command CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing_tbl(id INTEGER,
    lastName STRING,
firstName STRING,
PRIMARY KEY (id)): Error: User error in query: CREATE TABLE failed for table testing_tbl: Table exists but definitions do not match
```